# Automatically set decimal point (.) once user enters 2 digits from number decimal keyboard android Edittext

Tags: android, android-edittext, decimal-point

Automatically set decimal point  (.) once user enters 2 digits from number decimal keyboard in android Edit-text

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Create a class:-

```
public class DecimalDigitsInputFilter implements InputFilter
{
    Pattern pattern;

    public DecimalDigitsInputFilter(int digitsBeforeDecimal, int digitsAfterDecimal)
    {
        pattern = Pattern.compile("(([1-9]{1}[0-9]{0," + (digitsBeforeDecimal - 1) + "})?||[0]{1})((\\.[0-9]{0," + digitsAfterDecimal + "})?)||(\\.)?");
    }

    @Override public CharSequence filter(CharSequence source, int sourceStart, int sourceEnd, Spanned destination, int destinationStart, int destinationEnd)
    {
        // Remove the string out of a destination that is to be replaced.
        String newString = destination.toString().substring(0, destinationStart) + destination.toString().substring(destinationEnd, destination.toString().length());

        // Add the new string in.
        newString = newString.substring(0, destinationStart) + source.toString() + newString.substring(destinationStart, newString.length());

        // Now check if the new string is valid.
        Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(newString);

        if(matcher.matches())
        {
            // Returning null indicates that the input is valid.
            return null;
        }

        // Returning the empty string indicates the input is invalid.
        return "";
    }
}
```

Now set your edittext like this:

```
edittext.setFilters(new InputFilter[]{new DecimalDigitsInputFilter(2, 2)});
```

Comment: i already tried your updated code. that is working perfectly for restriction of numbers before and after decimal point but the issue (.) is not set automatically. manually user need to enter decimal point (.)

Answer (score 1):

Use `TextWatcher`:

```
editText.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {
    @Override
    public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {

    }

    @Override
    public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count, int after) 
    {

    }

    @Override
    public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {
        if (s.toString().length() == 2)
            editText.append('.');
    }
});
```

Comment: append() method not found .

Answer (score 0):

You can use TextWatcher for listening the text entered by the user then validate the length and then set the edittext text a that entered text+"."

Comment: i tried but whenever i enter any  text from keyboard  app get hanged completely.